# Preventing serialization of properties in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, serialization, asmx

I have a VB.NET class which I'm serializing via XML in an asmx file. I've added attributes to the datamember I want to ignore in serialization, but it's still returned. I also have the `<DataContract()>` attribute on my class and the `DataMember` attribute on all properties which should be serialized. My property declaration is:

```
    <ScriptIgnore()> _
    <IgnoreDataMember()> _
    Public Property Address() As SomeObject
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By adding an attribute to the backing field and converting it from an auto-property, I eventually got the proprty to stop serializing:

```
<NonSerialized()> _
Private _address As SomeObject = Nothing
<ScriptIgnore()> _
<IgnoreDataMember()> _
<Xmlignore()>
Public Property address() As SomeObject
    Get
        Return _address
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As SomeObject)
        _address = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: All you need, I think, is <XmlIgnore()>.

Comment: [XmlIgnore] stopped the field from serializing when the object was returned from an asmx page for me.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried the NonSerialized attribute:

```
<NonSerialized()> _
Public Property Address() As SomeObject
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, this gives:
Attribute 'NonSerializedAttribute' cannot be applied to 'Address' because the attribute is not valid on this declaration type.

Comment: You will need to change you property to not be auto-implemented to make it work, and put the attribute on the backing store.  I didn't realize that was the case.  Here is a link to an question that explains it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728367/how-to-prevent-auto-implemented-properties-from-being-serialized