# Trying to serialize a list of objects fails

Tags: .net, vb.net, serialization

I am trying to save a list of objects to file but getting an exception thrown in the process. This is my object class:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class FavoritesObject
    Private Dset As DataSet
    Private Name As String
    Private BSource1 As BindingSource
    Private Bsource2 As BindingSource

    Public Sub New()
        ' Leave fields empty. 
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal datset As DataSet, ByVal thename As String, ByVal binsource1 As BindingSource, ByVal binsource2 As BindingSource)
        Dset = datset
        Name = thename
        BSource1 = binsource1
        binsource2 = binsource2
    End Sub

    Public Property Dataset1 As DataSet
        Get
            Return Dset
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As DataSet)
            Dset = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property FavoriteName As String
        Get
            Return Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BindingSource1 As BindingSource
        Get
           Return BSource1
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As BindingSource)
            BSource1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property BindingSource2 As BindingSource
        Get
            Return Bsource2
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As BindingSource)
            Bsource2 = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Here are my functions for serialization and deserialization:

```
Public Sub WriteToBinaryFile(serializationFile As String, List As List(Of FavoritesObject))
    Using stream As Stream = File.Open(serializationFile, FileMode.Create)
        Dim bformatter = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
        bformatter.Serialize(stream, List)
    End Using
End Sub

Public Function ReadFromBinaryFile(serializationFile As String)
    Using stream As Stream = File.Open(serializationFile, FileMode.Open)
        Dim bformatter = New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
        Dim favorites As List(Of FavoritesObject) = DirectCast(bformatter.Deserialize(stream), List(Of FavoritesObject))
        Return favorites
    End Using
End Function
```

When I try to serialize my list of objects I get the following exception thrown:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Type 'System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource' in Assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

I am really unfamiliar with serialization and am trying to learn it. Can someone please shed some light on what my issue may be and a possible fix?

Comment: Isn't that obvious from the exception message that `BindingSource` is not supposed to (and can't) be serialized

Comment: The answer below gives the direct technical solution. The bigger problem is your design, a domain entity should not contain UI or Persistence code.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Didn't realize that thanks. In hindsight there was no reason to store them like that at all as they can be created on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a bit more I found this solution: [Preventing serialization of properties in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746444/preventing-serialization-of-properties-in-vb-net)

This is the code that seems to stop the serialization of the binding sources:

```
<NonSerialized()>
Private BSource1 As BindingSource
<NonSerialized()>
Private Bsource2 As BindingSource
```

Comment: Edited. Accidently included that.

Comment: The true answer here though is to remove the bindingsources altogether from the class as they do not need to be stored in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You have properties of type `BindingSource` which is not serializable,
you have to add the `XmlIgnore` attribute on the properties which are not serializable, like `BindingSource2` and `BindingSource1`

The code will be

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class FavoritesObject
Private Dset As DataSet
Private Name As String
Private BSource1 As BindingSource
Private Bsource2 As BindingSource

Public Sub New()
    ' Leave fields empty. 
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal datset As DataSet, ByVal thename As String, ByVal binsource1 As BindingSource, ByVal binsource2 As BindingSource)
    Dset = datset
    Name = thename
    BSource1 = binsource1
    binsource2 = binsource2
End Sub

Public Property Dataset1 As DataSet
    Get
        Return Dset
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As DataSet)
        Dset = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property FavoriteName As String
    Get
        Return Name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Name = value
    End Set
End Property

<NonSerialized()>
Public Property BindingSource1 As BindingSource
    Get
        Return BSource1
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As BindingSource)
        BSource1 = value
    End Set
End Property

<NonSerialized()>
Public Property BindingSource2 As BindingSource
    Get
        Return Bsource2
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As BindingSource)
        Bsource2 = value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Comment: Actually the needed attribute is called `NotSerialized` and should be set on backing fields.

Comment: Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Negative. Here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ivan's right. The OP is performing Binary Serialization (since he's using a `BinaryFormatter`), not XML Serialization.