# How can I have a required and nonSerialized attribute in my model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, requiredfieldvalidator, nonserializedattribute

In my Model I have things like that :

```
    [...]

    public string PasswordConfirm { get; set; }

    public string Captcha { get; set; }

    [...]
```

I would like that these two attributes are required but not serializable

I tried tu use [required] and [nonSerialized] annontations but without success. I already saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1728367/how-to-prevent-auto-implemented-properties-from-being-serialized)

But I don't know how to do what I want. It will be helpful for NonObtrusive-Validation, i want these field complete but i don't want to serialized them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my answer.

I can use the annotation [notMapped] which is compatible with [required], [compare] ...

I also use this :context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;  where I filled my base because i got a problem with validation here.